# Testing custom permission in django-rest-framework expected 201 but was 400

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-permissions

Problem is, I can't post the field "author" as you can see in the tests.py, and returns an error **"{'author': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "1" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]}"** see attached photo below.

**This is the error when running the test** *coverage run --omit='*/venv/*' manage.py test*

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHhfv.png)

**This is my code inside my tests.py**

```
    def test_create_post(self):
    """
    Ensure we can create a new Post object and view object.
    """
    self.test_category = Category.objects.create(name='django')
    self.testuser1 = User.objects.create_superuser(
        username='test_user1', password='123456789')
    # self.testuser1.is_staff = True

    self.client.login(username=self.testuser1.username,
                      password='123456789')

    data = {"title": "new", "author": 1, "excerpt": "new", "content": "new"}
    url = reverse('blog_api:listcreate')
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    print(response.data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
   queryset = Post.postobjects.all()
   serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'author', 'excerpt', 'content', 'status')
```

**Here's the models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Post(models.Model):

class PostObjects(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset() .filter(status='published')

options = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
)

category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
excerpt = models.TextField(null=True)
content = models.TextField()
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='published')
published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
status = models.CharField(
    max_length=10, choices=options, default='published')
objects = models.Manager()  # default manager
postobjects = PostObjects()  # custom manager

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-published',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried commenting other tests, resulting to only **one(1)** test running and also using **"$ ./manage.py test"** instead of **"coverage run --omit='/venv/' manage.py test"** works for me.

If anyone knows why this happened feel free to post/comment down below.